# First order differential equation problem for cone geodesics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this pair of equations, from considering geodesics on the cone:

$$u^2v'=h$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(2u'^2+u^2v'^2\right)$$

where $h$ and $E$ are constants. Apparently they lead to:

$$u\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(v-v_0)\right)=\frac{h}{\sqrt{2E}}$$

with the clue of trying $w=\frac{1}{u}$.

How do I prove that? I've tried combining the two equations to give:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(2u'^2+\frac{h^2}{u^2}\right)=E$$

Now

$$dw=-\frac{du}{u^2}=-w^2du$$

So

$$\frac{2}{w^4}\left(\frac{dw}{dx}\right)^2+h^2w^2=2E$$

$$\frac{\sqrt2}{w^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E-h^2w^2}}dw=dx$$

Edit: Corrections made per @Chappers comment.

Integrating both sides:

$$-\frac{\sqrt{E-\frac{h^2w^2}{2}}}{Ex}=x+A$$

So

$$E-\frac{h^2w^2}{2}=E^2x^2(x+A)^2$$

$$w=\frac{\sqrt2}{h}\sqrt{E-E^2x^2(x+A)^2}$$

$$u=\frac{h}{\sqrt2\sqrt{E-E^2x^2(x+A)^2}}$$

$$v'=\frac{2(E-E^2x^2(x+A)^2)}{h}$$

But once more, I don't appear to be heading towards the right solution.

Comment: You've lost a square when you substituted

Comment: @Chappers. Thanks, I'll correct and see how that simplifies things.

Comment: Have you studied Clairaut's relation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_relation)?

Comment: @JeanMarie: No, I haven't studied that. It's an interesting formula and is probably a good way to solve this, thanks. However, I'd rather stick to the maths that the course expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems simpler with the change of function $y=u^2$

[image]

Comment: Thanks. $y=u^2$ certainly simplifies the calculations.